# Future scheduled update request form

Tags: curl, pycurl, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

Using Smartsheet one can delete the future scheduled Update request forms via the UI.

Can I do the same using smartsheet API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Smartsheet API Documentation?  Specifically, check out the [Delete Update Request](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#delete-update-request) operation:

```
DELETE /sheets/{sheetId}/updaterequests/{updateRequestId}
```

To identify the **id** of the Update request that you want to delete (which you are required to specify when calling the **Delete Update Request** operation), you can use the [List Update Requests](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-update-requests) operation.